# Restore dump.rdb file in Azure Cache for Redis(basic tier)

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm working on migrating our existing on-prem redis to *azure cache for redis*. We have selected a basic tier plan.

I would like to restore the backup(dump.rdb) taken from our on-prem redis to azure redis. Tried several python SDKs but didn't work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-import-export-data did you try this?

Comment: @AlexAIT, thanks. As the link suggests , export/import is available only for premium plans.

Comment: You can try redis-copy. The tool is open source but not officially supported by Microsoft. https://github.com/deepakverma/redis-copy

Comment: @KalyanChanumolu-MSFT, thanks for the tool, however there are no instructions provided on how to use it. Could you please suggest any tools written in python